# Initializer syntax

Tags: c#, .net, object-initializers

I like the C# 3 [initializer syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer) and use it a lot, but today while looking in Reflector, the following came up:

```
var binding = new WSHttpBinding
{
  ReaderQuotas = { MaxArrayLength = 100000 },
  MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10485760
};
```

At first I thought it was a mistake, but it does compile! Guess I am still learning new stuff all the time.  :)

From what I can tell, it sets the `MaxArrayLength` property of the `ReaderQuotas` property of the `WSHttpBinding`.

Does this syntax create a new `ReaderQuotas` object and then set the property, or does it assume the property to be initialized already?  Is this the general way one would use to initialize 'child' properties?

I do find the syntax a bit confusing...

Comment: You may be interested in [this post](http://www.codeducky.org/even-concise-c-object-initializers/), which discusses the semantics and use-cases for this type of initializer

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, that doesn't create new objects unless you use `= new SomeType {...}`:

```
var binding = new WSHttpBinding
{
    ReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas { MaxArrayLength = 100000 },
    MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10485760
};
```

Your example shows the initializer syntax for setting properties of *existing* sub-objects. There is also a similar syntax for calling "Add" methods on collections.

Your code is *broadly* comparable to:

```
var binding = new WSHttpBinding();
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 100000;
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10485760;
```

Comment: Looks identical to that, is there more than just a syntactical difference? Looks as though (unless ReaderQuotas is initialized in the contructor of WSHttpBinding) it should throw an exception

Comment: Thanks, it just took me by surprise  :)  I assume by 'Add' you mean like a collection initializer?

Comment: @james: I would expect an exception in that case, but not having source code could prove confusing, if you dont know what gets done in the constructor. Some constructor overloads may or may not initialize that property, which will lead to even more confusion.

Comment: Not worth a whole extra answer - but this is discussed in Chapter 8 of C# in Depth. The first edition version of this chapter is available free from http://manning.com/skeet/

Comment: James, the difference is subtle. Though the code is semantically equivalent to that, we actually generate "temp = new Binding(); blah blah blah; var binding = temp;"  Why?  Because *the variable "binding" must not be used inside its own initializer!* That would be rather a chicken-and-egg problem.  If we generated the code exactly as Marc suggests then "binding" would be initialized *before the initializer code runs*, and someone could potentially observe "binding" in its partially-initialized state.

Comment: I might be wrong, but IIRC it also gets slightly different if there are multiple properties in the assignment, since in the initializer syntax the member is only evaluated once - so `..., SomeProp = { Foo = 1, Bar = 2 }` would be `var tmp = obj.SomeProp; tmp.Foo = 1; tmp.Bar = 2;`, and not `obj.SomeProp.Foo = 1; obj.SomeProp.Bar = 2;`.

Answer (score 15):

It is a bit confusing, I agree.

You should read section 7.6.10.2 of
the specification; it is all explained
there. For example:

> A member initializer that specifies
>   an expression after the equals sign
>   is processed in the same way as an
>   assignment to the field or property.
>
> A member initializer that specifies an
>   object initializer after the equals
>   sign is a nested object initializer,
>   i.e. an initialization of an embedded
>   object. Instead of assigning a new
>   value to the field or property, the
>   assignments in the nested object
>   initializer are treated as assignments
>   to members of the field or property.
>   Nested object initializers cannot be
>   applied to properties with a value
>   type, or to read-only fields with a
>   value type.
>
> A member initializer that specifies a
>   collection initializer after the
>   equals sign is an initialization of an
>   embedded collection. Instead of
>   assigning a new collection to the
>   field or property, the elements given
>   in the initializer are added to the
>   collection referenced by the field or
>   property.