# Nested object initializer syntax

Tags: c#, specifications, object-initializers

Resharper has just suggested the following refactoring to me:

```
// Constructor initializes InitializedProperty but
// the UninitializedSubproperty is uninitialized.
var myInstance = new MyClass();
myInstance.InitializedProperty.UninitializedSubproperty = new MyOtherClass();

// becomes

var myInstance = new MyClass
    {
        InitializedProperty = { UninitializedSubproperty = new MyOtherClass() }
    };
```

I've never seen this kind of object initialization before. In particular I don't see how

```
InitializedProperty = { UninitializedSubproperty = new MyOtherClass() }
```

makes any sense - it's not *assigning* anything to `InitializedProperty`.

Is this behaviour specified anywhere?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initializer syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020143/initializer-syntax)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This syntax is called [Object Initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397680.aspx). C# specification clearly gives a lot of examples on this subject:

### 7.6.10.2 Object initializers

> An object initializer
>   consists of a sequence of member initializers, enclosed by { and }
>   tokens and separated by commas. Each member initializer must name an
>   accessible field or property of the object being initialized, followed
>   by an equals sign and an expression or an object initializer or
>   collection initializer. It is an error for an object initializer to
>   include more than one member initializer for the same field or
>   property. It is not possible for the object initializer to refer to
>   the newly created object it is initializing.

Examples are:

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle
            {
                P1 = { X = 0, Y = 1 },
                P2 = { X = 2, Y = 3 }
            };
```

Compiles down to:

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
r.P1.X = 0;
r.P1.Y = 1;
r.P2.X = 2;
r.P2.Y = 3;
```

Having:

```
public class Rectangle
{
    public Rectangle()
    {
        P1 = new Point(); //default Point for demo purpose
        P2 = new Point(); //default Point for demo purpose
    }

    public Point P1 { get; set; }
    public Point P2 { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Point
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

Also consider reading a great chapter *8.3 Simplified initialization* in **C# in depth** book. Jon Skeet provides another look at advantages of using this kind of syntax for initializing tree-like structures.

Comment: Ah, thank you for poniting me at the spec - it's not so easy to find as all the examples online, and *none* of the examples I found did anything other than simple, top-level assignments. The spec *does* say that the object initializer can itself contain object initializers, which I guess is the key point.

Comment: @Rawling yes, there is an pseudocode for `object-initializer`, as C# spec gives for all constructs. I didn't wanted to bring that here, because formatting  was completely lost.

Comment: Which version of the standard are you referring to? As far as I can tell, the relevant section is 7.6.10.2 in version 4.5 and 5.0.

Comment: WOW, I also didn't know about this and the specification does not contain any example of this. Very cool and useful feature though. I see there is GitHub issue for that https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/12979

Comment: I have a related question. What if there was an extra level of nesting and we had to pass in an argument to "new Point(someArg)", where someArg is defined/set up at construction of Rectangle(). Thanks