# How to Select Specific Properties Through LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method which returns the object of type `CarsCache`. I want to set some properties in my object `Vehicle` which has object of `Car` from `CarChache` object. I can do it easily like below:

```
var carCahe =  getByCarId(1);

Vehicle v = new Vehicle();
v.Car.value1 = carCahe.value1;
```

But I want to do it through LINQ.  I have done something like this through LINQ but that method returns the collection and then I use where and select. I have a object `Vehicle` and there is an object `Car` in vehicle. I do it like this:

```
entity = new Vehicle
{

    IsActive = true,
    Car = DataCache.GetInstance()
          .GetAllCars()
          .ToList()
          .Where(o => o.carId== carId)
          .Select(o => new Car{Value1= o.value1, value2= o.value2})
          .Single()
    };
```

This is also working now I want to do this with method which returns only one object. Not collection but I am unable to do this. I am doing this:

```
entity =new Vehicle
{

  IsActive = true,
  Car= DataCache.GetInstance() // it retruns carCahe object.
         .GeTCarById(1)
         //Here i want to set value1 property and value2 property
 };
```

How can I do this?

Comment: IMO, When return value of `GeTCarById` is a car with new values your approach is correct ;).

Comment: To be honest: If your first approach is working, why do you want to make it more complicated and less readable? The first approach is totaly clear just by seeing it once for me. The LINQ approach is much more error-prone, less debugable, less readable and actually not needed if the other one is working.

Comment: @ckruczek agreed. LINQ is slow but i just want to do it for my knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a nice way to implement the second approach using LINQ, as `getByCarId` returns just single item, not list. LINQ methods often operate on enumerables, so you cannot use methods like `Select` in your case.

Why don't you get the data from cache in first statement and assign it to use it to create `Vehicle` in another statement:

```
var carCache = DataCache.GetInstance().GeTCarById(1);
var entity = new Vehicle
{
  IsActive = true,
  Car = new Car { Value1 = carCache.value1, value2 = carCache.value2 }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I done it. Can we do this in object initializer?

Comment: Both `Vehicle` and `Car` are already using object initializers. However you could simplify initializing of `Car` property as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794925/nested-object-initializer-syntax

Answer (score 2):

Please try like this:

```
var carCache = DataCache.GetInstance().GeTCarById(1);
entity =new Vehicle
{
    IsActive = true,
    Car.value1 = carCache.value1,
    Car.value2 = carCache.value2
};
```

I assume `Car` property in class `Vehicle` has already filled `Car` object somehow - at least `new instance`.