# Object Initializers, Non-Public Children, and Nested Initialization

Tags: c#, initialization, object-initializers

I was looking through my codebase and found a line of code that R# had helpfully refactored for me. Here's a representative sample:

```cs
public class A
{
    public B Target { get; private set; }
    public object E { get; set; }

    public A()
    {
        Target = new B();
    }
}

public class B
{
    public object C { get; set; }
    public object D { get; set; }
}

public static class Test
{
    static A LocalA;
    static void Initialize()
    {
        LocalA = new A
        {
            E = "obviously this should be settable",
            Target =
            {
                C = "Whoah, I can set children properties",
                D = "without actually new-ing up the child object?!"
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Essentially, initialization syntax allows for setting a child object's public properties without actually performing the constructor call (obviously if I pull the `Target` constructor call from the constructor of `A`, the whole initialization fails due to a null reference.

I've searched for this, but it's difficult to put into Google-able terms. So, my question is: (a) what is this called exactly, and (b) where can I find some more information in C# documentation about it?

---

### Edit

Looks like someone else has asked this with similar lack of documentation found:
[Nested object initializer syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794925/nested-object-initializer-syntax)

Comment: Huh. Nice example. Who'd a thunk that this was possible? I would prefer something more explicit. At some threshold inline initializers just look terrible. This crosses that threshold, IMO.

Comment: I kind of agree - what is *actually* happening becomes a little less explicit. Additionally, the behavior is constrained to this particular example, as far as I can tell - you can't just initialize properties for an already-constructed `object` outside of some parent initializer.

Comment: Hrmmm, I was going to answer that you need to look at Object initializers, but you already tagged that in the post...however that is what is happening here. Maybe I am misunderstanding the question

Comment: Yeah, I looked back over the documentation but can't find any mention of this particular behavior: setting the properties of `Target` without actually setting `Target` itself

Comment: Is there a way to summon Jon Skeet on here?

Comment: It's all in there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794925/nested-object-initializer-syntax

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initializer syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020143/initializer-syntax)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794925/nested-object-initializer-syntax

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing concrete in the documentation that I see on this topic of `Object Initializers`, but I did decompile the code, and here is what it actually looks like once decompiled:

```
        A a = new A();
        a.E = "obviously this should be settable";
        a.Target.C = "Whoah, I can set children properties";
        a.Target.D = "without actually new-ing up the child object?!";
        Test.LocalA = a;
```

A known fact on `Object Initializers` is that they always run the constructor first. So, that makes the above code work. If you remove the initialization of `Target` in the constructor of `A` you will get an exception when the property initializers are tried since the object was never instantiated.

Comment: Right - it's just really fascinating that there's this little gem of initialization syntax sitting out there that most people seem to be unaware of...

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer and I agree its really difficult to put this into a language that google understands

In this case you are assigning values to  `C` and `D` which are public properties of `Target` object

```
 LocalA.Target.C = "Whoah, I can set children properties";
 LocalA.Target.D = "without actually new-ing up the child object?! Nope I dont think so:)!"
```

You are not actually initializing a `new B()` as the `Target` setter is Private. This is obviously going to fail if B is not initialized.

Comment: Yeah - I'm pretty clear on what it's doing, just trying to find some documentation on the nuances of object initialization and what other little tricks I can play with it. Thanks though!